# Cubic-Bezier transition has a delay in IE and Edge

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

my Cubic-bezier transition doesnt work, it has a weird delay in Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge.

The Problem:

If you hover over the Links in IE or Edge it has a delay and multiple Links have the Hover color and no Ease-Out.

**Here is the CSS:**

```
a,
.uk-link {
  color: #ec4e72;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer; 
  -webkit-transition: all 0.667s cubic-bezier(0.16, 1, 0.29, 0.99);
  transition: all 0.667s cubic-bezier(0.16, 1, 0.29, 0.99);
}
```

**Here is the HTML:**

```
<li>
  <a class="uk-link-muted" href="/test">test</a> </li>
  <li>
    <a class="uk-link-muted" href="/test">test</a>

    </li> 
  <li>
    <a class="uk-link-muted" href="/test">test</a>
    </li>
```

Here is the Codepen https://codepen.io/yokogfx/pen/eEYmva
The uk-link-muted is just for changng the Color, this doesnt change the Bug :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Issue got Fixed in the new Fall Creators Update!